# git remote branch multiple elements reference

Tags: git, reference, branch, git-remote

A public Git repository was cloned to local storage. The repository is for MSM SoC Linux kernel development.

```
git remote show origin
```

generates a long list of tracked remote branches.
Here an example of one list item

> caf/linaro/linux-linaro-stable/v3.14/topic/arm64-apm     tracked

**Question 1**
What type of stuff does the element *topic* refer to?
What type of stuff does the element *v3.14* refer to?
What type of stuff does the element *linux-linaro-stable* refer to?
What type of stuff does the element *linaro* refer to?
What type of stuff does the element *caf* refer to?

I am **not** asking for the function the particular point might have in the addressed project. I am asking **just** for the type of the stuff/object.

**Question 2**
Why must the reference to the *arm64-apm* branch include all these elements?
Why can't it be in the simple form

```
<remote name>/<branch name>
```

as learned from most Git books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the slashes you see in `caf/linaro/linux-linaro-stable/v3.14/topic/arm64-apm tracked` are just part of the branch name.  To understand better, consider referring to the following remote tracking branch on your local Git setup:

```
git checkout -b origin/caf/linaro/linux-linaro-stable/v3.14/topic/arm64-apm tracked new_branch
```

Here, the first slash separates the remote (`origin`) from the rest of the branch name (`caf/linaro/linux-linaro-stable/v3.14/topic/arm64-apm tracked`).

We use BitBucket for our Git hosting, and branches with slashes in their name appear to be treated no differently than branches with no slashes.  The slashes are just a convenient way to create a meaningful Git branch name.  They may *logically* separate the branch name into different parts, but *semantically* they do not have any meaning.

Comment: Thanks for informative answer! Possibly, branch name of this form reflects the name of parent branch the addressed branch derivates from, and the grand-parent's name the parent derivates from, and so on.   Does your experience confirm that?

Comment: Yes, it does.  At least, this is one common use-case for using paths in the Git branch name.

Comment: So put short, naming branches this fashion is good to document the parent-child branch relationships, otherwise plotting history graphs is necessary which might be effort extensive.

Comment: Yet further conclusion, the elements in reference form as addressed here do refer to branches, grand-branches, grand-grand.... But they do that just in textual way, no referencing engine behind that. The link between the text block and the branch being referenced by it to must be made by human.

Comment: So, I guess the remote names can, at least, theoretically also include slashes. One reaches the point where the stuff gets dangerous. When one reference include remote name and branch name and both include slashes it can be hard to distinguish these two parts. That might be the reason why the folks generally avoid such situation. For this, possibly, nobody uses slashes in remote names, because it is known practice the branch names to include possibly slashes.